# Share data between devices (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, synchronization

I am using Swift to try and share a string across multiple Apple devices. It is the same app on all the devices (iPad, iPhone and Mac) but I am trying to get it so I can have the string on all devices and update it when it changes, so basically 'sync' the string.

I am trying to do it with NSUserDefaults at the moment and just save it to a list, then retrieve it when the app launches, but I am having some trouble because the code I am following is in objective-c and I am bad at translating code. I have put the code below so that you can translate it if you can.

Code:

```
//On one device:
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation];

//on the other:
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
for (NSString *key in dictionaryRepresentation.allKeys) {
    id ob = dictionaryRepresentation[key];
    [defaults setObject:ob forKey:key];
}
```

If you can't translate it, do you have a better way of syncing a string across multiple devices, for free, using Swift?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the expectation is by saving a string in `NSUserDefaults` will automatically sync across devices, the expectation is wrong. You could use `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore ` with iCloud for this purpose. Ref. `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html

Comment: Here's a "tutorial" using swift http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Synchronizing_iOS_8_Key-Value_Data_using_iCloud

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` will not share across devices. It is local to each copy of the app. You could use `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` with iCloud as suggested by @bobnoble in his comment, but that will likely take from 10s of seconds to a couple of minutes to propagate.

If you want it to be fast I would suggest setting up a BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) link between your apps. The sending device would send a BLE "advertisement" and the receiving devices would listen for that advertisement. That would be fast, but limited to BLE range.

Note that writing BLE is pretty low-level stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the translation of this code would be the following:

```
//On one device:

let dict = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation()

//on the other:
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
for key : NSString in dictionaryRepresentation.allKeys {
    let ob = dictionaryRepresentation[key]
    defaults.setObject(ob, forKey:key)
}
```